# Mavic wheels out of true after 200km, is normal?

Tags: wheels, carbon

I bought set of Mavic wheels, and today I noticed that the front and rear wheel is around 1,5mm out true after 200km of ride. Im curious whether it is normal.

[I have pair of those](https://www.deporvillage.com/rueda-trasera-mavic-cosmic-pro-carbon-17-nucleo-shimano-700x25-negro-blanco)

Comment: The wording of the question could be changed to apply to all new wheels. As there is nothing Mavic specific in the answer.

Comment: A lot has to do with whether the wheel builder pre-stresses (and then retrues) the wheels as the last step in manufacturing.  Premium wheel builders will do this, but most "factory" wheels are not pre-stressed, and hence they need a break-in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normal for a new rim to be out of true after first rides. Once the first service for the rim is done, it should remain true for thousands of kilometers.

It is recommended to check a new rim after 200-1000 km of riding.

I recommend using a professional mechanic to true the wheel. It is easy to overtighten some of the spokes, if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected. The wheel needs to set. The interfaces to the spokes in the rim and the hub flanges are slightly deformed during the first rides. You may also find the spoke tension much too low now.

The spokes need to be properly tensioned now and the wheels centred again. They should hold well afterwards.

Comment: This is not expected at all for a decent quality wheelset. We don't know which wheels the OP has and whether they should be expected to be decently built.

Comment: The OP posted a link to Mavic Cosmic Carbon.